# $f(x)$ is a monotonic function prove the following

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, inequality, summation

Prove that:

$ \rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^n f(\frac{k}{n})\sum_{k=1}^n k{f(\frac{k}{n})}^2\le\sum_{k=1}^n kf(\frac{k}{n})\sum_{k=1}^n{f(\frac{k}{n})}^2 $

Given $f(x)$ is a positive function and also monotonic decreasing function.

Comment: divide through by  $(\sum_{k=1}^n f(\frac{k}{n}))^2$ and it looks like a correlation inequality, you want to show that the 2 increasing functions k and $f(\frac{k}{n})$  are positively correlated under etc.  which is true and easy

Comment: I didnt follow it ? Can you elaborate it please

Comment: I see you have an answer , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality is slightly abstract, but mentions the case you need.  your case can also be done by the very intuitive rearrangement inequality, which is duscussed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Comment: Hmmm... I dont see a trivial way by rearrangement inequality.Already tried that method! But i guesss FKG will work

Comment: write it down for all permutations and sum over the permuations, and it gives the correaltion inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $a_k=f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right).$
(Proof by induction). Let $P(n)$ be the statement $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\left(f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)^2\leqslant\sum\limits_{k=1}^n kf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)^2$$ or, in shorter form
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k\sum\limits_{k=1}^n ka_k^2\leqslant\sum\limits_{k=1}^n ka_k\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k^2.$$

1. (Basis) For $n=1$ we have: $a_1\cdot a_1= a_1\cdot a_1$
2. (Induction step). We assume that $P(n)$ is true and prove that $P(n+1)$ is true. For LHS of $P(n+1)$:
   \begin{equation}
   \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} ka_k^2 = 
   \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k +a_{n+1} \right) \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k a_k^2 + (n+1) a_{n+1}^2 \right)=\\ 
   \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ka_k^2 + (n+1)a_{n+1}^2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k + a_{n+1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ka_k^2 + (n+1)a_{n+1}^3 \leqslant \\ 
   \sum\limits_{k=1}^n ka_k\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k^2 + (n+1)a_{n+1}^2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k + a_{n+1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ka_k^2 + (n+1)a_{n+1}^3\overset{def}{=} A.
   \end{equation}  RHS of $P(n+1)$ equals:
   \begin{equation}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} ka_k\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k^2 = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ka_k + (n+1)a_{n+1}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 + a_{n+1}^2 \right) = \\
   \sum\limits_{k=1}^n ka_k\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k^2 + (n+1)a_{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 +a_{n+1}^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ka_k + (n+1)a_{n+1}^3\overset{def}{=} B. 
   \end{equation}  Next,
   \begin{equation}
   A-B= \left((n+1)a_{n+1}^2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k + a_{n+1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ka_k^2 \right) - \\
   \left( (n+1)a_{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 +a_{n+1}^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ka_k \right) = \\
   (n+1)a_{n+1} \left(a_{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2 \right) + a_{n+1} \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ka_k^2 - a_{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k a_k \right)=\\
   a_{n+1}^2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left((n+1)a_k -k a_k \right) + a_{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(k a_k^2 - (n+1)a_k^2 \right)=\\
   a_{n+1}^2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} {a_k(n+1-k)} - a_{n+1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} {a_k^2(n+1-k)}=\\
   a_{n+1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(a_{n+1}a_k (n+1-k) - {a_k^2(n+1-k)} \right)=\\
   a_{n+1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{(n+1-k)(a_{n+1}a_k  - a_k^2)}=\\
   a_{n+1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{(n+1-k)a_k(a_{n+1}  - a_k)}<0
   \end{equation} since $\{a_k \}$ decreases.